# Как извлечь числа регулярным выражением?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Привет всем!

Есть строка, которая всегда содержит `AAAA_num1_num2`.
`AAAA_` - всегда одни и те же символы.
`num1`, `num2` - это числа (int).
Разделены все символы этим: `_`.

Я извлекал числа с помощью Int.parse, но хотелось бы регулярным выражением это сделать. Можете показать как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: `Regex` оперирует строками, `int` он вам не вернет, зачем вам регулярка тут? `s.Split('_')` - и дальше `int.Parse(res[1])`, `int.Parse(res[2])`.

Comment: AAAA_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) - еще как вариант к имеющимся ответам

Comment: Кстати, `\d` матчит не только арабские цифры, но и `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`. и даже `൫` он считает цифрой, так что осторожнее с ним

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следующий код извлечет все числа из строки:

```
  string pattern = @"\d{1,}";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string s = ...;

  foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(s))
     Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

По ссылке можно поэкспериментировать:
https://regex101.com/r/NxqnC7/1

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, если опустить всевозможные проверки, так:

```
var match = new Regex(@"_(\d+)_(\d+)").Match();
var num1 = int.Parse(match.Groups[1]);
var num2 = int.Parse(match.Groups[2]);
```

Скобки в регулярке преобразуются в группы. Причем групп всегда на одну больше (группа с индексом 0 - сам match)

Comment: Почему-то System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex в match.Groups ругается на Groups

Comment: и это еще: error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\d'